# How to set rounded rectangle radius in PowerPoint using C#?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm writing a VSTO add-in for PowerPoint, which needs to adjust radius of rounded rectangle numerically.

I have searched the offical docs, and can only found `Shape.Adjustment` is READ-ONLY, and `Shape.Adjustment.Item` seems been removed from Office 365. But it's weird that same thing can be done via VBA.

So I wonder if I missed some segment of docs, or it's impossible to do that in C#?

Answer (score 0):

OK, It looks there are fewer people working on the VSTO. I have found where the problem locate, and FYI:

`Shape.Adjustment` is actually setable, so it seems the doc made a mistake, and rather that  `Adjustment` has a child named `Item`, `Shape.Adjustment.Item` actually means that `Shape.Adjustment` is indexable, so you can directly get its value using `Shape.Adjustment[1]`.

Comment: Shape.Adjustment returns a read-only object, but the object has read/write properties (returned by indexing into the object's .Item collection), so strictly speaking, the docs are correct. Obtuse, perhaps, but correct. Note that some shapes have more than one adjustment, so you might need to use .Adjustment[2] or higher.